# No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hql

I have the HQL where I trying to get artifacts that have no classification (when active is 0)

```
artifacts = Artifact.findAll("FROM Artifact WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT artifact_id FROM Classification WHERE active = 1) AND document_id = :docid",[docid:document.id], [max:limit, offset:startIndex]);
```

Whenever I run I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'artifact_id' {originalText=artifact_id}
```

Classificaiton definition:

```
class Classification {

    public static final String USER_DEFAULT = "USER"
    public static final String USER_SYSTEM = "SYSTEM"

    TaxonomyNode node
    String artifactId 
    Boolean active
    String createdBy
    String updatedBy
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated


    static constraints = {
        node nullable:false, blank:false
        artifactId nullable:false, blank:false, unique: ['node']
        active nullable: false, blank: false
        createdBy nullable:false, blank:false
        updatedBy nullable:false, blank:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'classification_seq']
        artifactId index: 'classify_by_artifact_node'
        node index: 'classify_by_artifact_node'
        active defaultValue: "1"
    }
}
```

You can refer to previous problems I faced to understand what exactly I am trying to do [Quest 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469285/sql-to-hql-query-grails) and [Quest 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467420/how-to-check-null-or-not-valid-in-hql-query)

Comment: It would be helpful to see Classification definition

Answer (score 104, accepted):

SQL queries use column names while HQL queries use Class properties.  You're selecting artifact_id from Classification but the Classification class has no property named 'artifact_id'.  To fix it, use the class property in your HQL.

```
SELECT artifactId FROM Classification
```

Comment: If you give any alias to the table/entity then that needs to be used. For examlple `SELECT c.artifactId FROM Classification c`

Answer (score 36):

It occurs sometimes when keyword 'new' is missed for your DTO (DATA TRANSFER OBJECT).

Answer (score 1):

I get identical error when I've :

```
 @NamedQuery(name="Contact.findAll",query="SELECT c from Contact")
```

it fixed by uppercasing the `from` and adding the `c` as alias to `Contact` class

```
@NamedQuery(name="Contact.findAll",query="SELECT c FROM Contact c")
```