# Return substring starting from the N occurrence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

How to use this function in `QueryDsl` in Querying JPA

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)
```

Returns the substring from string `str` before `count` occurrences of the delimiter `delim`.

**UPDATE 1 :** 
After trying @MaciejDobrowolski solution like this :

```
QAcheteur ach = new QAcheteur("ach");
new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(ach)
 .list( Expressions.stringTemplate("SUBSTRING_INDEX({0},',',1)", ach.ancestors)  );
```

I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' {originalText=SUBSTRING_INDEX}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'acheteur1_.ancestors' {propertyName=ancestors,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=ancestors,path=ach.ancestors,tableAlias=acheteur1_,className=persistence.Acheteur,classAlias=ach}
       |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'acheteur1_.ID_ACHETEUR' {alias=ach, className=persistence.Acheteur, tableAlias=acheteur1_}
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'ancestors' {originalText=ancestors}
       +-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: '',''
       \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '3'
```

**UPDATE 2 : (Solution)**
Following @DraganBozanovic's answer i create my custom dialect to get ride of `No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode` because `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is unknown in `JPA` so we use our own dialect to make it work.

```
package dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

    public CustomMySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("substring_index", new StandardSQLFunction("substring_index", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        registerFunction("replace", new StandardSQLFunction("replace", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        ....
    }
}
```

And in JPA configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      ...
      ...
     <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">dialect.CustomMySQLDialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
</bean>
```

P.S : I decide to write the solution because it was a combination of two answers.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler I try `path.substring(path.locate(",", count))` but locate function don't start from N occurrence but from a index

Comment: @Youssef Please share your code if possible.

Comment: okey @SkyWalker I share the part when i execute a test query, If you want something else tell me.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way would be to use `Expressions.stringTemplate`

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("SUBSTRING_INDEX({0},',',3)", columnPath)
```

*update*

Ok, I've managed to get it work.
I am using `H2 Database`, so I used function `SUBSTR`.

```
QAcheteur ach = new QAcheteur("ach");
new JPASQLQuery(entityManager, new H2Templates())
        .from(ach)
        .list(Expressions.stringTemplate("SUBSTR({0}, 1, 3)", ach.ancestors));
```

The key was to use not `JPAQuery`, but `JPASQLQuery` as this query uses native function. All you have to do is to follow [this](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e431) tutorial.

Comment: thanks @MaciejDobrowolski but why the `Integer.class` ? the function must return a string

Comment: @Youssef sorry, I read wrong function definition :) corrected, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: thanks @MaciejDobrowolski but now i got a exception `No data type for node` i made a update in my question so you can see exception log.

Comment: thanks MaciejDobrowolski  but the solution was a combination between your answer and @DraganBozanovic 's answer. so i'm confused what answer to award

Answer (score 1):

### Exceptions occur from this:

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("SUBSTRING_INDEX({0},',',3)", ach.ancestors)
```

### Exception: No data type for node

SQL queries use column names while HQL queries use Class properties. You're selecting artifact_id from Classification but the Classification class has no property named 'artifact_id'. To fix it, use the class property in your HQL.

```
SELECT artifactId FROM Classification
```

### Resource Link:

1. [No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471534/no-data-type-for-node-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-tree-identnode-hql)

Comment: @Youssef If possible, You can share your code through github so that i can generate locally and can help.

Comment: it's a big project how can i share it ? and also i work with svn not with github

Comment: @Youssef you can follow this https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion/

Comment: i can't it's a private project for the company i work and you have to generate a big database to use my code

Answer (score 1):

[Register the custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909315/how-can-you-call-custom-database-functions-with-hibernate) in the Hibernate dialect:

```
registerFunction("substring_index", new StandardSQLFunction("SUBSTRING_INDEX", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
```

Then you will be able to invoke it from JPQL/HQL (and with the Querydsl on top of JPA).

Comment: but i use the literal `1` just for test it can change dynamically or have as value a other integer column.

Comment: @Youssef Ok, I was not aware of that.

Comment: @Youssef You could register the custom function to be able to call it from JPA queries. Edited the answer.

Comment: thanks DraganBozanovic the solution was a combination between your answer and @MaciejDobrowolski 's answer. so i'm confused what answer to award

Comment: @Youssef You shouldn't worry about that, wait until the end of bounty period and let the community decide by voting. :) Also, maybe some other good answer shows up as well in the following days...

Comment: Okey @DraganBozanovic i update my question with my solution for the people who will face this problem. .. and if you can help me up there http://stackoverflow.com/q/38015366/1383538 i will be thankfull