# No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an SpringBoot app with this query

```
 @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update HotelDailyPrice cdp  set cdp.price = (select nvl (avg (cp.price),0) "
            + "from HotelPrice cp where cp.hotel = ?1 and cp.updateDate > ?2), cdp.day = ?3 where cdp.hotel = ?1 ")
    void updateDailyAveragePrice (Hotel Hotel, Date dayDate, String dayDateString);
```

But I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'nvl' {originalText=nvl}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'avg'
       |  \-[DOT] DotNode: 'hotel1_.price' {propertyName=price,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=price,path=cp.price,tableAlias=hotel1_,className=com.hotels
.backend.persistence.domain.backend.HotelPrice,classAlias=cp}
       |     +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'hotel1_.id' {alias=cp, className=com.hotels.backend.persistence.domain.backend.HotelPrice, tableAlias=hotel1_}
       |     \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'price' {originalText=price}
       \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '0'
```

This problem happens after add **nvl** in the query

Comment: you mean because "NVL" is not a valid function in JPQL ? as the JPA spec says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use coalesce instead of nvl ... This the the jpql equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to class variables for HQL unlike columns for sql queries.

Refer to the already answered question.

[No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471534/no-data-type-for-node-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-tree-identnode-hql)